# count function mechanism in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

suppose we have this code

result of count() function is about each query or after queries
executes then count function return result ?

```
$model=Model::query()

foreach ($Entities as $entity) {
               $model->orWhereBetween("id",$entity->first_id,$entity->last_id])
         }
$model->count()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model=Model::query()

    foreach ($Entities as $entity) {
        $model->orWhereBetween("id",$entity->first_id,$entity->last_id])
    }

//$model - object of query builder
$model->count();
```

It will generate one query and calculate on the db side: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ? OR id BETWEEN ? AND ? OR id BETWEEN ? AND ?`

Answer (score 0):

Salam ,

Answer : **It depends on when you call count method !**

In your code :

```
$model=Model::query();
$model2 = $model;

foreach ($Entities as $entity) {
//you should save your where between in self $model varriable
    $model = $model->orWhereBetween("id",$entity->first_id,$entity->last_id])
}

//$model - object of query builder
$model->count();//After operations and filtering 
$model2->count();//Before operations and filtering (  It is equal or more than $model->count()  )
```

I hope this helps you :)